# Deploy roslyn application

Tags: c#, deployment, inno-setup, roslyn

How can I deploy a roslyn app? I am using the Inno to create an instalator but I don't know how to do it when my app using the roslyn. Does exist any end-user dll or compiler instalator of the roslyn? Or any other way how to do it? I have to do it without instaling Roslyn CTP for VS 2012, because it is my bachelor's thesis.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roslyn is a set of DLL files, along with a compiler (EXE) that uses those DLLs to generate ordinary CIL assemblies.

If you're running new code through the Roslyn parser at runtime, you can deploy the DLLs the same way you deploy other DLLs, subject to the license of the CTP.

Assemblies created by the Roslyn compiler are no different from other assemblies.

Comment: And how can I found the roslyn dlls?

Comment: From wherever you referenced them in your project.

Comment: Ok so I found the dlls but no exe file

Comment: @wolen: You don't need the EXE.

Comment: Yes, you are right but you must control VS because it automaticly relinks dll's copy to original files. Now it is workinf perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @wolen: Set `Copy to output directory` on the reference

Comment: I copied the dlls to Release file and sets references and it works. And when I tried to removed the dlls and run file so VS relinks to the original ones. But when I just add dlls and creates links so it works.